# Why do they torture me so?

Tags: riddle

Even though I couldn't escape if I wanted to, they keep me locked in a cage.
They decide when I eat and force me to eat the same meal day in and day out.
When they finally decide I can eat, they beat me.
If I scream in protest, they gag me.
Every night they bind my hands and feet before allowing me to sleep.
They have been doing this to me my entire life.
Why do they torture me so?

Comment: how did you write this? I thought I cut the internet connection in my basement? and where did you get a computer or phone?

Comment: @marius - Now that I see the answer to the question, your comment reminds me of a colleague who recently had a dream that her soon-to-be _answer_ was sending her messages on Facebook, complaining about the current living conditions.

Comment: @YowE3K I read this as saying that a Stack Exchange answer she hadn't even posted yet was on Facebook :-P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you

> An infant?

Even though I couldn't escape if I wanted to, they keep locked me in a cage.

> A crib

They decide when I eat and force me to eat the same meal day in and day out.

> They=parents, meal=breastmilk

When they finally decide I can eat, they beat me.

> Getting burped

If I scream in protest, they gag me.

> Pacifier to stop crying

Every night they bind my hands and feet before allowing me to sleep.

> Swaddled before bed

They have been doing this to me my entire life.

> You're a baby.

Why do they torture me so?

Comment: "Why do they torture me so?" In punishment for waking them up so much. Let me _sleep_, child! Please!

Answer (score 10):

You might be a

> Fuel consuming vehicle

---

Even though I couldn't escape if I wanted to, they keep locked me in a cage.

> Cage means garage.

They decide when I eat and force me to eat the same meal day in and day out.

> You eat fuel

When they finally decide I can eat, they beat me.

> When you start, the pistons move very fast.

If I scream in protest, they gag me.

> If you won't start, I will push the accelerator even more

Every night they bind my hands and feet before allowing me to sleep.

> I park you safely

They have been doing this to me my entire life.

> Yup.

Why do they torture me so?

> We don't torture you...It's what you need to do. For us.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> An alarm clock?

Even though I couldn't escape if I wanted to, they keep locked me in a cage.

> The alarm clock can't escape but its kept in metal casing

They decide when I eat and force me to eat the same meal day in and day out.

> Flicking the switch to supply electricity

When they finally decide I can eat, they beat me.

> Pressing buttons to set the time of alarm

If I scream in protest, they gag me.

> When the alarm goes off you turn it off

Every night they bind my hands and feet before allowing me to sleep.

> They set the time?

They have been doing this to me my entire life.

> Every night and every day

Why do they torture me so?

> Because you are an alarm clock?